# Import CSV using PHP not recognising new line characters?

Tags: php, excel, csv, import

I'm working with PHP and CSV files exported from Excel.

My script to read the lines is as follows:

```
$lineseparator = "\r\n";
$csvcontent = fread($file,$size);

fclose($file);

foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {
    print $line."END<br>";
}
```

However, it doesn't recognised the new lines. If I use a proper symbol such as ; it does. I want to make this as easy as possible for the used, so they can export it from Excel. The trouble is Excel just exports it with new lines instead of symbols.

Why isn't this picking up the new line characters?

Comment: Have you tried a simple "\n"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a CSV file, you should really be using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use \n\r instead of \r\n or just try it with only \n, cus that should definitly work, depends on your system.
\n = new line
\r = return carret

Or you have to configure your excel as character separation. With the ; and ,